# How to make into Buffer? - Trying to decode MessagePack Axios response to JSON or JavaScript Object notation

Tags: javascript, axios, msgpack

I'm trying to decode a MessagePack response from a backend call using Axios that looks like this:
��matches����attendance��away_team�� etc.

into a format where I can access its contents (e.g. JSON or JavaScript Object). Simply using msgpack-lite's decode doesn't work on it, as it needs to be a Buffer. How can I make this response into a Buffer? As far as I know, a Buffer needs to look like `<Buffer 82 a4 6e 61 6d 65 a8 4a 6f 68 6e 20 44 6f 65 a3 61 67 65 0c>`

Comment: Buffer.from(<your string>)

Comment: I do receive a buffer from your answer, but it looks a bit weird. It has "ef bf bd" repeated throughout the Buffer, probably representing the � I would say? I tried to plug the first part of the buffer into http://kawanet.github.io/msgpack-lite/ and see what the answer would be. 

Buffer.from(<my string>) resulted in:

<Buffer ef bf bd ef bf bd 6d 61 74 63 68 65 73 ef bf bd 03 ef bf bd ef bf bd 00 11 ef bf bd 61 74 74 65 6e 64 61 6e 63 65 ef bf bd ef bf bd 61 77 61 79 5f 74 ... 2067316 more bytes>

Comment: If you plug in the first part of the buffer into that website and remove "ef bf bd" from the start then you'll see that it matches my MessagePack Response. However, it makes the characters for JSON/JS Object disappear!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue! I was typing "arrayBuffer" for the responseType header in Axios instead of "arraybuffer" lol